# Grafana visualisation of non time series data

Tags: visualization, grafana, influxdb

I have two columns in my InfluxDB database : Values and Iterator count
I want visualise this on Grafana where my x axis is iterator count and value on y axis is basically corresponding to each iterator count.
EXAMPLE

Iterator Count(X) | Value

1 | 46

2 | 64

3 | 32

4 | 13

5 | 12

6 | 11

7 | 10

8 | 9

9 | 12

10 | 25.

Is it possible to achieve visualisation for the same, having no aspect of time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [plot.ly plugin](https://github.com/NatelEnergy/grafana-plotly-panel)

You just need to specify `Iterator Count(X)` as the x-axis in the trace section and `Value` as the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
One more thing - Is there a way where we could dynamically filter the name of the trace? instead of manually writing the trace name, we can select data from the database on a specific query and name the trace automatically. Is this possible?